# why does this tar command fail when passed as string in ssh call?

Tags: bash, ssh, tar, sudo

```
ssh user@server "sudo tar -czf - -C /path/To/Directory *.properties" | tar xzf -
```

It fails with following error -

> tar: *.properties: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

If I ssh to server and then on server, instead of `tar -czf -` use `tar -czf abc.tgz` and remove the piped command at the end, it works correctly i.e. compress all the .properties file from the directory?

I have tried using --wildcards parameter as well as -P and the complete path ending with *.properties, but they didn't work either.

Comment: I should also add that - when there is . instead of *.properties, the command works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell at the far end expands *.properties in `user`'s home directory, before it execs `tar`. I'm guessing there's no matching files in `~user`.

What you probably want is something more like (assuming `user` can access the directory)

```
ssh user@server 'cd /path/To/Directory && sudo tar -czf - *.properties' \
    | tar xzf -
```

Or, use `tar`'s `--wildcards` option, and stop the remote shell expanding the argument:

```
ssh user@server 'sudo tar -czf - -C /path/To/Directory --wildcards \*.properties'
```

Comment: but -C flag is suppose to change directory, isn't it? Also, I cannot cd to the directory as I need to have root privelege, and sudo cd path/to/directory does not work

Comment: I found a way around to my problem -- ssh user@server "sudo sh -c 'cd /path/To/Directory; tar -czf - *.properties'" 
    | tar xzf -

Comment: accepting the answer as the original command was indeed looking into the home directory, though I believe with -C flag it should not have.

Comment: It's the shell that expands wildcards; tar's `-C` flag doesn't come into it.

Comment: You mentioned `tar --wildcards` - that should work, **if** you prevent the remote shell trying to expand it: `ssh u@s 'sudo tar -czf - -C /path/To/Directory --wildcards "*.properties"'`